How to derive $V = -\textbf{m}\cdot \textbf{B}$?
Why is the potential energy of the magnetization $\textbf{m}$ in an induction magnetic field $\textbf{B}$ given by
$$V = -\textbf{m}\cdot \textbf{B} \text{?}$$
I don't understand how to start from any combination of the four Maxwell's laws or the electromagnetic force $$\textbf{F} = -\textbf{$\nabla$}V = q(\textbf{E}+\textbf{v}\wedge\textbf{B})$$ where $q$ is the electric charge of a particle and $\textbf{v}$ is its speed.
What are the steps of the derivation ?

What have you tried? Have you looked in any books on E&M?

From
$$U_B^{\text{int}}(x_1,x_2)=-\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int \mathrm{d}^3x\mathrm{d}^3x'\frac{j_1(x)\cdot j_2(x')}{\lvert x-x'\rvert} \tag{1}$$
we write
$$U_B^{\text{ext}}=-\int \mathrm{d}^3xj(x)A_{\text{ext}}(x) \tag{2}.$$
Then to first order, this equation becomes
$$U_B^{\text{ext}}=-A_{i,\text{ext}}(0)\int \mathrm{d}^3xj_i(x) -\partial_kA_{i,\text{ext}}(0)\int \mathrm{d}^3x j_i(x)x_k +\ldots \tag{3}.$$
The first term vanishes and we write the second one as $\int \mathrm{d}^3x j_i(x)x_j=-\epsilon_{ijk}m_k$. This gives
$$
U_B^{\text{ext}}=\epsilon_{ikl}\partial_kA_{i,\text{ext}}(0)m_l+\ldots \\ =-\epsilon_{ikl}\partial_iA_{k,\text{ext}}(0)m_l+\ldots \\ =-B_l(0)m_l +\ldots \tag{4}$$
which is in vector form:
$$U_B^{\text{dipole}}(x)=-m\cdot B_{\text{ext}}(x)\tag{5}.$$
For more details, see Maggiore's Modern Introduction to Classical Electrodynamics (2023).
Origin of (1):
We set $\rho =0$
From Maxwell's equations using Coulomb's gauge,
$$\Box A(x)=-\mu_0j + \frac{1}{c^2}\nabla \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} $$.
This equation reduces to the first term for $\rho=0$.
Solving this differential equation you get that
$$A(x)=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int d^3x'\frac{j(x')}{\lvert x-x'\rvert}$$
This allows you to find an equation for B(x)
$$B(x)=\nabla \times A(x)$$
Now that we know A and B we can build the magnetic force between two static currents distributions using Lorentz force. This is
$$F_1=-\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int d^3xd^3x'j_1(x)\cdot j_2(x') \frac{x-x'}{\lvert x-x' \rvert^3}$$
And naturally $$F_1(x_1,x_2)=-\frac{\partial U_B^{int}}{\partial x_1}$$
So we finally deduce equation (1).

I can't show last equation in latex format, does someone know why ?

I just fixed it! (you had put a ")" instead of a "}")

Oh okay thank you !

How did you get (1)? The question asks to explain this based on Maxwell's equations and the Lorentz force formula...

I added an edit to the post so it includes a synthesis of the derivation of (1).
